# 3dsmax - Snap a single vertex of an object to a 0,0,0 (world), moving the entire object with it

Tags: 3ds-max

I need to position an object at 0,0,0 in the world for game engine purposes. Exporting as an OBJ seems to ignore the pivot entirely.

Currently, I'm using a cube with a corner at 0,0,0 and lining the object up by eye but this is tedious and non-exact. How do you actually do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select your object, click on the move tool, right-click on the move tool to get the dialog. Type `0 0 0` your object will be moved to the origin.

Comment: Thanks. And for completeness, I had to snap the pivot to the desired vertex first.